# How to remove values from Shared

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am working on android using kotlin, I have saved userId in shared preferences but when I try to remove it, it didn't removed. Am I doing it right?

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            val pref = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("Auth", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            
            val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = pref.edit()
            editor.remove("UserId")
            editor.commit()
  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign out",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

Login code, this is my fun which I am calling when user login and it is called like this:

```
saveUserIdSession(mAuth.currentUser.uid.toString())
```

```
fun saveUserIdSession(id: String) {
        val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? =
            this.activity?.getSharedPreferences("Auth", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences!!.edit()
        editor.apply{
            putString("UserId", id)
        }.apply()
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you save the "UserId" in the first place? I am assuming on loign.

Comment: How are you determining it is not removed? Please show that code.

Comment: If you use -> setSharedPreferences("key" , "");  then also removed the values.

Comment: It works now! there was a slight mistake in the logic. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deleting Android Shared Preferences in one line :-)**

```
context.getSharedPreferences("Auth", 0).edit().clear().commit();
```

Thanks,
Programiner

**Note:- Upvote Answer if Helpful.**

Comment: OP is already doing this for the specific item in the code they showed.

Comment: yaa, but the good way to do is like in the answer

Comment: Only if they need to delete every entry. If they need to delete a single entry, they’re doing it correctly. Either way, the root of their problem is something else because their code should have worked.

Comment: Yeah, I try but still unable to remove value from Shared Preferences.

Comment: @Nadish you want to remove the value of only the preference (Auth) ?

Comment: Yeah only have to remove auth value.

Comment: It works now! there was a slight mistake in the logic. Thanks everyone!